# Why do Protocol Service Multiplexers can take only ODD numbered values between 1 and 32,767?

Tags: networking, acl

I am following a book called Bluetooth Essentials for Programmers and I am not much experienced, in the book it doesn't explain the reason of the odd-numbered values and I couldn't find information about that. Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is because the Bluetooth standard says this is the way it has to be:

> The structure of the PSM field
>   is based on the ISO 3309 extension mechanism for address fields. All PSM
>   values shall be ODD, that is, the least significant bit of the least significant
>   octet must be ’1’. Also, all PSM values shall have the least significant bit of
>   the most significant octet equal to ’0’. This allows the PSM field to be
>   extended beyond 16 bits.

I haven't read the full core specification in any great detail, so I can't go into the full reasoning behind this, but you are free to download and do so from the [Bluetooth.org website](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications).

Comment: 1 in the LSB is a flag for the last octet.